# Boolean condition is not executing in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have code in which I am doing database operation using Room database. I want to change the Icon if the user favourite an item and if user tap on the same icon it changes to an other icon.I am able to set the favourite icon but when user tap on the icon again it doesn't change. Here is my code

```
var isfavorite by Delegates.notNull<Boolean>()

OncreateView(){
isfavorite=false

}

add_fav.setOnClickListener {
         if(!isfavorite) {
             add_fav.setImageResource(R.drawable.star)
             favoriteViewModel.InsertData(
                 requireContext(),
                 edit_text_fiele.text.toString(),
                 translated_textview.text.toString()
             )

             isfavorite=true

         }
         if(isfavorite){
             add_fav.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorites)
         }
     }
```

Comment: And where is code opposite to isfavorite=true?

Comment: You need to use if/else instead of two if statements. Both of your statements get executed the way you have it now. Also, there is no need for the delegate if you are initializing the property in the constructor.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks .. Solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you set isfavorite=false; in onCreateView method.

```
OncreateView(){
```

isfavorite=false
}

now when first time you clicks button, it invokes the below method

```
add_fav.setOnClickListener {
     if(!isfavorite) {// here isfavorite is false, that's why it will execute the //code.
```

then you change the isfavorite value to true just before second if condition.

```
isfavorite=true

     }
     if(isfavorite){//here is favorite is true. and it will go inside 
         add_fav.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorites)
     }
```

next time whenever you will click on button, due to isfavorite is true, it will not go in first if condition.

to make it working you have to reset the isfavorite value to false in second if condition.

```
    if(isfavorite){//here is favorite is true. and it will go inside 
                 add_fav.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorites)
                 **isfavorite=false**
             }
```

Comment: Yeah I was doing this mistake. And the other mistake was using two if statements rather than if else.

Comment: Cool. let me know if something came up.  happy coding. @Alihassan